# Find a new geo coord moving a given distance and angle from a previous point

Tags: coordinate-system, geodetic

I'm not interested in plotting or converting to Cartesian, just following a traverse from one lat/lon to a new one.

Given two ends of a runway in decimal latitude & longitude

1. Calculate the angle to true north of the center line connecting the two points
2. Use that angle to traverse a fixed distance to a new point, also expressed in lat/lon

When finished, I'll export to KML.

My input data is in geo so I don't want to look up a local coordinate system to convert to state plane and then back to geo.

Once I have the angle, let's say 10 degrees, then I want to find the geo coord that's 200 feet and 10 degrees from the previous geo coord, then a second point 10,000 feet away at the same angle (effectively extending the line a set distance)

Comment: Bearing between two points is solved by the "Reverse Problem" of geodesy (aka "Inverse"), and locating a point at bearing and distance is the "Forward Problem" of geodesy (aka "DIrect"); both are able to be solved (or approximated) in most computer languages (and most geodetically aware GIS applications). What is missing is any attempt to solve the problem -- Choose a platform, language, method, and code library, and give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks. Working in Python, I envisioned a model but having problem finding a formula or code library. I will give a look for the terms you provided.

Comment: It's a partial differential equation only solvable by iterative means, so it's not just a formula (more like a cascade of them).  Lots of code libraries will do this. The US National Geodetic Survey has FORTRAN source that implements the Vincenty algorithm, though porting that to Python wouldn't be pretty.